# CSS: display:inline-block invisible padding

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/QYtnL/

```
<div id="wr">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

#wr {
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
#wr > div {
    display:inline-block;
    background:black;
    font-size:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

How to remove that annoying padding, to make all divs 0px height?
If i'm removing `display:inline-block;` , it's gone, but i need `inline-block`.

Comment: add height:0px; to #wr

Comment: What "padding" are you talking about? Which browsers are affected? What do you mean by "all divs", does that include `#wr`? What have you tried so far, and why didn't your solutions work?

Comment: Your `<div>`s all have 0px height. Is your container one that doesn't, as shown by the red background you so wisely put.

Comment: But why does #wr have some height? If it's childrens are empty? O_o

Comment: This will nullify text-align:center; effect.

Comment: #wr is the height of your natural line-height and font-size, surely if you are centering the elements then you will have content in the inner divs in which case the padding will be filled by the content

Comment: What do you mean by natural line-height?

Comment: #wr will have inherited a line-height from somewhere (most likely your body)

Comment: Great! line-height:0px;font-size:0px; on #wr have worked... Why haven't i tried it from the start... Probably working 24 hours last few days have made me careless. Thanks Pete.

Comment: Move your comment to the answers, i'll accept it. :)

Comment: @Somebody I just came to know from the above comments. giving just `font-size:0px` is enough. no need of `line-height:0px` (becomes automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pete suggested in above comments, give `font-size:0px; line-height:0px` to `div#wr`.

In my opinion, giving just `font-size:0px` is enough as the `line-height` value depends on the `font-size` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float:left` like this..

```
#wr>div{
    display:inline-block;
    background:black;
    font-size:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Like i said, this will nullify effect of text-align:center

Comment: you can add only display:inline if you don't want to see block elements :)